# How can I exclude a certain checkbox class from a jQuery filter if another class's checkbox is already checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I'm brand new to coding and have no idea what I'm doing. I feel like I'm not very good at explaining things, either, so I'm sorry if this post is a bit hard to understand. Hopefully looking at the code itself makes more sense.

Basically, I have a list that can be filtered. Each list item contains multiple classes. I also have checkboxes to display each individual class.

However, there are a couple of classes that overlap in terms of list items they apply to but are not exactly the same.

Say, for example, somebody wants to look for things in Class A, but *not* include things in Class D. If Class A is checked, it will automatically display all list items that Class D also applies to.

What I would like to do is make it so that if Class A is checked, you have the option to also exclude Class D from your search, so that overlapping data can be displayed. Vice versa applies too (ie if Class D is checked, have an option to exclude Class A).

I would also like this to apply to all classes if at all possible. So that you can have one (or more) classes checked, but at the same time, exclude a certain class you aren't interested in, even if list items overlap (ie you have Class D checked, and don't want list items in Class B that are *also* in Class D).

```
<div class="options">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="operation" value="union" id="op-union" checked>Union
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="operation" value="intersection" id="op-inter">Intersection
  </label>
</div>

<div class="categories">
  <span class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" value="classa" id="cat-classa">
    <label for="cat-classa">Class A</label>
  </span>
  <span class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" value="classb" id="cat-classb">
    <label for="cat-classb">Class B</label>
  </span>
  <span class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" value="classc" id="cat-classc">
    <label for="cat-classc">Class C</label>
  </span>
  <span class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" value="classd" id="cat-classd">
    <label for="cat-classd">Class D</label>
  </span>
  <span class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" value="classe" id="cat-classe">
    <label for="cat-classe">Class E</label>
  </span>
  <span class="category">
    <input type="checkbox" value="classf" id="cat-classf">
    <label for="cat-classf">Class F</label>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
  <ul>
    <div class="filterDiv classa classd"><li>List 1</li></div>
    <div class="filterDiv classa classe"><li>List 2</li></div>
    <div class="filterDiv classb classd classe"><li>List 3</li></div>
    <div class="filterDiv classc classf">List 4</li></div>
    <div class="filterDiv classb classd classf">List 5</li></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Given the nature of the list, any combination of class and type is possible. Typically, there is only one class, but on occasion there are two. In the actual list, I have far more than just three classes attached to one list item, too.

Script:

```
<script>
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".categories input");
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", filter);
}
var radios = document.getElementsByName("operation");
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("change", filter);
}
filter();
function filter() {
  var i, j;

  // Choose an operation
  var operation = document.getElementById("op-union").checked ? "union" : "intersection";

  // Get the selected categories
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".categories input");
  var categories = [];
  var c;
  for(i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
      c = checkboxes[i].value;
      categories.push(c);
    }
  }

  // Apply the filter
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".filterDiv");
  var item, show;
  for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    if(categories.length == 0) {
      show = true;
    } else if(operation == "union") {
      // Union: Only one of the categories needs to exist
      show = false;
      for(j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
        if(item.classList.contains(categories[j])) {
          show = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      // Intersection: All of the categories must apply
      show = true;
      for(j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
        if(!item.classList.contains(categories[j])) {
          show = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if(show) {
      item.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      item.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks heaps in advance to anyone who helps! Once again I apologise for the wording, I'm new to this and still figuring my way around it all. Any attempts are much appreciated.

Comment: Why are there only two radio buttons ("A or B" and "A and B") when there are many other options, e.g. "A or C", "A and C", etc.)? It sounds like you could get rid of the radio buttons and add another checkbox: "[_] Verbatim?". If that box is checked, it means show items with *exactly* the selected class(es), and if it's not checked (which would be the default), show items that contain *at least* those selected classes. Also, it's not clear whether you would want an option for "show items containing *any* of these classes (not just *all* these classes). I suggest you clarify your requirements.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing with the radio buttons. They're there because of the union and intersection differences, and I haven't played around with them all that much. I wasn't thinking about them when I made the post and accidentally left them as they're labelled on the page itself - they don't actually refer to A and/or B like I said in my post. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

your code is fine. you need some modifications. I was not changing your code style but if you are using javascript better to use the let keyword(modern javascript) don't use var anymore and try to understand forEach loop that reduces your code(except if your are using break statement)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="options">
  <label><input type="radio" name="operation" value="union" id="op-union" checked>A or B</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="operation" value="intersection" id="op-inter">A and B</label>
</div>

<div class="categories">
<span class="category"><input type="checkbox" value="classa" id="cat-classa"><label for="cat-classa">Class A</label></span>
<span class="category"><input type="checkbox" value="classb" id="cat-classb"><label for="cat-classb">Class B</label></span>
<span class="category"><input type="checkbox" value="classc" id="cat-classc"><label for="cat-classc">Class C</label></span>
<span class="category"><input type="checkbox" value="classd" id="cat-classd"><label for="cat-classd">Class D</label></span>
<span class="category"><input type="checkbox" value="classe" id="cat-classe"><label for="cat-classe">Class E</label></span>
<span class="category"><input type="checkbox" value="classf" id="cat-classf"><label for="cat-classf">Class F</label></span>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
<ul>
<div class="filterDiv classa classd"><li>List 1</li></div>
<div class="filterDiv classa classe"><li>List 2</li></div>
<div class="filterDiv classb classd classe"><li>List 3</li></div>
<div class="filterDiv classc classf">List 4</li></div>
<div class="filterDiv classb classd classf">List 5</li></div>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
  
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".categories input");
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", filter);
}
var radios = document.getElementsByName("operation");
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("change", filter);
}
filter();
function filter() {
  var i, j;

  // Choose an operation
  var operation = document.getElementById("op-union").checked ? "union" : "intersection";

  // Get the selected categories
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".categories input");
  var categories = [];
  var c;
  for(i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
      c = checkboxes[i].value;
      categories.push(c);
    }
  }
 

  // Apply the filter
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".filterDiv");
   items.forEach(item=>item.style.display='block')
  var item, show;
  for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i];
    if(categories.length == 0) {
      show = true;
     
    } else if(operation == "union") {
      // Union: Only one of the categories needs to exist
   
      show = false;
      for(j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
        if(item.classList.contains(categories[j])) {
        
          show = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!show){
        item.style.display="none";
      }
    } else {
      //  console.log(operation)
      // Intersection: All of the categories must apply
      show = true;
      for(j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
        if(!item.classList.contains(categories[j])) {
          item.style.display="none";
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    // if(show) {
    //   item.classList.add("show");
    // } else {
    //   item.classList.remove("show");
    // }
  }
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```